# Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, phasset

I load photos from PHAssets. I get this error log when I load some images and pass them to another view controller. I can't seem to find anything online about this. Anyone encounter this and know what it is?

I also get this error along with it:

```
***** Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/
```

Comment: Probably related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764363/error-logging-directory-does-not-exist-var-mobile-library-logs-crashreporter-d

Answer (score 16):

There may be following reason :

`1.)`It may occur when we try to use multiple Image view (Image) so just image and try to release it , it will solve  problem.

`2.)`Also to avoid create too many property for storing images .

`3.)`If we need to send image to another view try to compress it .

Answer (score 0):

leaving this here hoping this could help:

import photos

```
import Photos
```

then in your info.plist add photo usage description this is mandatory for privacy reasons

create and empty array of data like this

```
var imgData = [Data]()
```

then in your viewdidload check for authorisation like this

```
if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized{
        print("already allowed")
        getImages()
    }else{
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] (newStatus) in
            if newStatus == .authorized{
                print(newStatus)
                self?.getImages()
            }else{
                print("not accepted")
            }
        }
    }
```

create a function

```
func getImages(){
        let assetCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumDepthEffect, options: nil).firstObject!
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil)
        result.enumerateObjects { (ph_asset, int, unsafe_mutable_pointer) in
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: ph_asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data, string, image_orientation, info) in
                self.imageData.append(data!)
                self.imageString.append(string!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

extend you view controller like below

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(imageData.count)
    return imageData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell
    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
    print(imageString[indexPath.item])
    if let dvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController{
        dvc.data = imageData[indexPath.item]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
    }}}
```

the problem could be because you are passing the image, but if you pass the data this will work, in your detailviewcontroller do this

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!{
    didSet{
        myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}
```