# Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLog/

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, ios8, runtime-error, osx-yosemite

**UPDATE: SUBMIT BUG REPORTS AND REFERENCE THIS NUMBER: #18882445**

I keep having this error come up randomly through various compile times (even if nothing seems wrong with the app)

```
[PLLogging] ***** Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/
```

I can't find anything online.

I have tried cleaning the project, multiple devices, and re-installing Xcode. If you have any advice on this issue I'd love to hear it!

I am running Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite and all the devices tested were running OSX 8.1

Comment: I'm still on 10.9 and I get this error - same thing. Very strange...

Comment: Hi Aggresssor, I am getting the same error on picking up image from gallery.Please post your solution if you could get any.

Comment: I filed a bug report, and they didn't reply :/

Answer (score 2):

Just go to, `iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings`. It will restore the default settings for iOS Simulator. Remember it will also removes all apps installed in Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in iOS. Restarting the device fixed my issue. Also check the default camera app. In my case default camera was also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some programming with the file manager so it's probably related.

Exit Xcode, delete all of the DerivedData and restarted iPad, now works.

Xcode 6.2, iOS 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I was tried to use parse with a swift project. I tried to delete all the libraries that I was using and add them again but didn't work so I restored my project from the last git version and I manually adding the new versions of the files. It is not fancy solution but Is quicker than fight with xcode to solve the issue.