# Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have downloaded a Source code from Apple docs, [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

and i'm having some wearied issues that i face never, when i take a video than stop the recording it gives me that issue in console "`[PLLogging] ***** Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/`"

Please help me.

Comment: so, did you fire that bug to apple ?

Comment: man, who ask those question filled bug to them

Comment: Related (this question should probably be closed as a dup): [Error: logging directory does not exist /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLog/](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26764363/608639).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in iOS. Restarting the device fixed my issue. Also check the default camera app. In my case default camera was also not working.